# How to put placeholder text in filter input Kendo UI Grid with Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Kendo UI Grid with Angular and I cannot find a way to put some text/placeholder in filter inputs with Typescript.

In my code I use kendoGridFilterCellTemplate:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="sender" title="Sender" width="80">
      <ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter let-column="column">
        <kendo-grid-string-filter-cell [showOperators]="false" [column]="column" [filter]="filter">
        </kendo-grid-string-filter-cell>
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

By default filter inputs in Kendo UI Grid have no inputs/placeholders and I would like to put something like:

```
        <kendo-grid-string-filter-cell [showOperators]="false" [column]="column" [filter]="filter" placeholder="Search...">
        </kendo-grid-string-filter-cell>
```

Kendo Grid won't recognize **placeholder** html element.How can I achieve this without using jQuery?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your question and help us to help you please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and add an [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

To put placeholder text inside kendo-grid-string-filter-cell, add it through `DynamicPlaceholder` attribute.

```
 <kendo-grid-string-filter-cell
    [showOperators]="false"
    [column]="column"
    [filter]="filter"
    [DynamicPlaceholder]="'Action Title'"
  >
  </kendo-grid-string-filter-cell>
```

if needed, `ActionTitle` string variable can be pass as below.

```
 <kendo-grid-string-filter-cell
    [showOperators]="false"
    [column]="column"
    [filter]="filter"
    [DynamicPlaceholder]="ActionTitle"
  >
  </kendo-grid-string-filter-cell>
```

This works every time, this is a live code example. Used version - `@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^5.4.0`